# AWK - Using Variables in shell

Tags: awk

I have an input file like:

```
INFO  2016-06-15 00:10:43.173WMSPackingOrderManager    llocatePackingOrderToWorkplaceBoxed -Remaining capacity of workplace WMSPackingWorkplace[428654,PAC_MB_ 104] is -43
INFO  2016-06-15 00:30:43.173WMSPackingOrderManager    llocatePackingOrderToWorkplaceBoxed -Remaining capacity of workplace WMSPackingWorkplace[428654,PAC_MB_ 104] is -43
INFO  2016-06-15 00:30:43.173WMSPackingOrderManager    llocatePackingOrderToWorkplaceBoxed -Remaining capacity of workplace WMSPackingWorkplace[428654,PAC_MB_ 104] is -43
INFO  2016-06-15 00:30:43.173WMSPackingOrderManager    llocatePackingOrderToWorkplaceBoxed -Remaining capacity of workplace WMSPackingWorkplace[428654,PAC_MB_ 104] is -43
INFO  2016-06-15 00:30:43.173WMSPackingOrderManager    llocatePackingOrderToWorkplaceBoxed -Remaining capacity of workplace WMSPackingWorkplace[428654,PAC_MB_ 104] is -43
```

The code I currently have is as follows:

```
cat inputFile.log | awk -v date="2016-06-15" -v startTime="00:10" -v endTime="00:20" '$2" "$3>=from&&$2" "$3<=to' from=date" "startTime to=date" "endTime
```

I am trying to get the `from` and `to` to use the variables provided but to no luck. I have tried escaping the special characters with `\` but this didn't seem to effect it.

Comment: no need to say `cat file | awk '...' `, since `awk '...' file` does the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this

```
cat inputFile.log | awk -v date="2016-06-15" -v startTime="00:10" -v endTime="00:20" 'BEGIN{from=date" "startTime; to=date" "endTime}($2" "$3)>=from && ($2" "$3)<=to'
```

or

```
awk -v date="2016-06-15" -v startTime="00:10" -v endTime="00:20" 'BEGIN{from=date" "startTime; to=date" "endTime}($2" "$3)>=from && ($2" "$3)<=to' inputFile.log
```

without use `cat`. Thanks to @Ed Morton

**Output**

```
INFO  2016-06-15 00:10:43.173WMSPackingOrderManager    llocatePackingOrderToWorkplaceBoxed -Remaining capacity of workplace WMSPackingWorkplace[428654,PAC_MB_ 104] is -43
```

Comment: Legend. Works like a charm.

Comment: Can you explain how `"$3>=from&&$2" "$3<=to'` this works?

Comment: `'$2" "$3>=from&&$2" "$3<=to'` this code is just a string comparison and it will compare the string in alphabetic order, `from` and `to` was defined in the `BEGIN` scope, so `from="2016-06-15 00:10"` and `to="2016-06-15 00:20"`.

Comment: Some white space and parens would clarify: `(($2" "$3) >= from) && (($2" "$3) <= to)`. I'm upvoting the awk part but lose the UUOC.

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks for you advice!